# Jackson dependency issue on Eclipse: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, jackson

I am new to jackson. I have set up a test sample to make sure that I am able to use jackson on my Eclipse environment. However, it seems that I got some unexpected error while compiling my simple code on Eclipse, and I have searched a bit and do not know how to resolve it. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

I have added the .jar files to the "Build Path" of my project, as shown below.

[image]

My code is quite simple just for testing the dependency:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;

public class JacksonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
    }
}
```

When I compile the code on Eclipse, it throws an error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory`

More details of the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory
    at jacksontest.JacksonTest.main(JacksonTest.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

Could anyone tell how to resolve it? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. Silly me! I should add the jar to classpath not modulepath